# Min and Max on 'datetime' column not showing correct result in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Data time column:

[image]

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],'%d/%m/%Y %H%M')

print (df['DateTime'].min())
print (df['DateTime'].max())
```

[image]
​

```
df['DateTime'].dtype
>>dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

As seen in the fig the first entity, min() would be `31/07/2020 19:31`but output giving wrong also same with the max() it is wrong

Comment: I think problem is there is another minimal and maximal value, because `min` and `max` for datetimes working well. Or is possible mixed dates with first months and with first days?

Comment: Another test is use `print(batch['DateTime'].sort_values())`

Comment: thanks but i found the problem `:` was missing between `%H` and  `%M`

Comment: what is `print(batch['DateTime'].sort_values())` ?

Comment: it was showing same result , wrong min and max

Comment: I added `:`  between '%H` and `%M` it is correct now